# FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, google-play-services

I am facing an error caused by Firebase Api.
Here is error log:

```
Firebase API initialization failure.   
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>:(Ljava/lang/String;)V from class com.google.firebase.iid.zzg
```

And here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
}
```

What can it be the problem?

Comment: Is the text shown the complete contents of your build.gradle?  The first line should be `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` must be at the bottom, after the dependencies.

Comment: It's not complete gradle. It's just related parts with google-services. @qbix

Comment: I have the same problem. Still no answer :(

Comment: @NinoLenoska see my answer below. It looks like it is some weird dependency problems with Firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I added firebase dependency and updated gms library versions this error is fixed.

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: @NinoLenoska This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the Firebase dependencies themselves depend on a specific version of the `com.android.support` libraries. I changed all of mine to 25.1.1 (found by Android Studio complaining about different versions) and that has fixed problem for me!

So for your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
   ...
}
```

Edit: This is what Android Studio is complains about when I added Firebase
[image: Android Studio complaining about versions]

Comment: I tried your answer but it didn't resolve my problem. I tried 25.0.0, 25.1.1, 25.2.0 and 25.3.0. Still got error..

Comment: @EmreAlparslan take a look at my edit and see if your Android Studio does something similar, the version you need might be different