# FirebaseApp still fails even after removing from gradle

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio

> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
>
> F/FirebaseApp(23028): Firebase API initialization failure.

every time I compile the error appears.

tried

> flutter clean
> tried going to every gradle file and removing firebase(did not find anything).

search for string firebase on any text file in the folder and found nothing.

how to remove firebase from the build?

version android studio artic force
flutter 61.2.2
dart 203.8452

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624633/firebaseapp-firebase-api-initialization-failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed the gradle, however the marge from the suggested answer was too complex for me.
so the gradle build from the example was helpfult and used that .

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```